# 404 Error when making a POST request using fetch()

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, post, fetch

I am following [this tutorial from  Hakernoon](https://hackernoon.com/setting-up-node-js-with-a-database-part-1-3f2461bdd77f)  to set up Node.js with MySQL using my machine as local server.
I am using a few different tools, but they don't seem to be a problem. I'm using:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Node.js
- MySQL Workbench (He uses Homebrew because his is a Mac)
- MySQL
- knex.js
- Express

*(Ubuntu and Workbench are the only differences)

Summarizing,the whole tutorial works well except when I reach the part of 'Login'. Here, we build a form to enter the user name and password making a `POST` requests. Then, if everything is OK, it returns a `200 status`, else shows a message saying the login failed. And here is the problems. Every time I try to log in (even when being sure the credentials are correct and knowing that that user is stored in the database) it tells me that the login fails.

Checking on the browser inspect tool, it shows a `Fail to load resources: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not found)`. It also points out that the problems is in the `fetch()` function I use in my `post` function to make the `POST` requests.

I checked the documentation on `fetch()` but is does not clarify much. Also I tried to contact the author of the tutorial and I got no answer. What am I doing wrong with fetch to give me the 404 status?

Also, every time I create a new user (also a `POST` request), it does it with no problem and I can see it in the database in MySQLWorkbench.

This is the file (app.js) with the code to create users and login:

```
const CreateUser = document.querySelector('.CreateUser')
CreateUser.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const username = CreateUser.querySelector('.username').value
    const password = CreateUser.querySelector('.password').value
    post('/createUser', { username, password })
})

const Login = document.querySelector('.Login')

Login.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const username = Login.querySelector('.username').value
    const password = Login.querySelector('.password').value

    post('/login', {username, password})
        .then(({status}) => {
            if(status === 200)
                alert('login success')
            else 
                alert('login failed')
        })
})

function post (path, data) {
    return window.fetch(path, {   <========= Here is where the browser shows the problem
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
}
```

***I am not posting the rest of the code to not make it too long, if more info is needed, let me know). Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide an image or text evidence of "the browser showing the problem"?

Comment: Double check your routes. It might help. Are you sure that /login route exists and accepts post requests?